# Flask selfreferential many to many relationship, how to query

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working on a flask app that manages a database of notes. Idea is that these notes can refer at one another. Making these references works fine but I don,t succeed in querying them so that on the page of a specific note can be shown at what notes this note refers at and what notes refer at this note.
This is the model I use:

```
references = db.Table('references',
    db.Column('refers_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('note.id')),
    db.Column('is_referred_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('note.id')))

class Note(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(140), index=True, unique=True)
    timestampCr = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text)
    external_source = db.Column(db.String(300))
    internal_document = db.Column(db.String(300))
    timestampRe = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    timestampUp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    category = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, nullable=False)
    referred = db.relationship(
        'Note', secondary=references,
        primaryjoin=(references.c.refers_id == id),
        secondaryjoin=(references.c.is_referred_id == id),
        backref=db.backref('references', lazy='dynamic'), lazy='dynamic')
  
    def __repr__(self):
        return '[Note] {}' .format(self.title)
```

This is the view for the page to display an individual note:

```
@app.route('/readnote/<id>')
def readnote(id):
    note = Note.query.filter_by(id=id).first_or_404()
    note.timestampRe=datetime.utcnow()
    db.session.commit()
    return render_template('readnote.html', id=id, note=note)
```

And this the html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
   {% if note.category %}
    <h2>Category</h2>
    {% endif %}
    <h1>{{note.title}}</h1>
    <p>{{note.content}}</p>
    <p>Created at {{note.timestampCr.strftime('%A %d %B %Y')}}</p>
    <p>Latest edit at {{note.timestampUp.strftime('%A %d %B %Y')}}</p>
   {% if note.external_source %}
   <p>External source:
    <a href="{{note.external_source}}" target="_blank">{{note.external_source}}</a></p>
   {% endif %}
   {% if note.internal_document %}
   <p>Internal document:
   <a href="../static/files/{{note.internal_document}}" target="_blank">{{note.internal_document}}</a></p>
   {% endif %}
   <a href="{{ url_for('editnote', id=id) }}">Edit note</a><br>
   <a href="{{ url_for('requestdeletenote', id=id) }}">Delete note</a><br>
   <a href="{{ url_for('addref', id=id) }}">Refer to another note</a><br>
   <a href="{{ url_for('addrefinv', id=id) }}">Make another note refer to this one</a><br>
{% endblock %}
```

I have tried numerous examples on how to query many to many relationships but I don't manage to translate them properly to the specific case of the selfreferential many to many situation. I would appreciate a suggestion for the right way to query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the referred/referenced notes, you can iterate the `referred` and `references` attributes of a note in your template.

```
<h1>{{note.title}}</h1>
<p>{{note.content}}</p>
<h2>Referred</h2>
<ul>
{% for n in note.referred %}
<li>{{ n.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
<h2>References</h2>
<ul>
{% for n in note.references %}
<li>{{ n.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
<p>Created at {{note.timestampCr.strftime('%A %d %B %Y')}}</p>
```

I would also recommend using

```
note = Note.query.get_or_404(id)
```

as it's more concise.

Comment: Thanks, does exactly what I wanted it to do.